# Loading csv into pandas dataframe only reads 6 columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file into a dataframe. The original csv has about 111 columns (not all needed, I want to drop some columns later) but on loading the data, the resultant dataframe only has 6 columns, though has the correct amount of rows (~300).

I have double checked this by setting the options to display the whole dataframe.

Any ideas why this might be?

I can't see anything wrong with the csv, this is the header row of the csv (sorry its so long)

Edit:
This is the code I have used:

```
    processdf = pd.read_csv(thefile, compression='gzip')
```

> timestamp,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,valveOpen,sontexTimestamp,sontexModbusAddress,sontexModbusParity,sontexModbusFlowControl,sontexModbusStopBits,sontexModbusCustomID,sontexModbusFabricationNo,sontexModbusFirmwareVer,sontexModbusBaudRate,sontexModbusRunningHours,sontexErrors,sontexEnergyUnit,sontexEnergyDecimals,sontexEnergyTotalizerHeating,sontexEnergyTotalizerTariff1,sontexEnergyTotalizerTariff2,sontexEnergyStoredST1,sontexEnergyTariff1ST1,sontexEnergyTariff2ST1,sontexEnergyStoredST2,sontexEnergyTariff1ST2,sontexEnergyTariff2ST2,sontexVolumeUnit,sontexVolumeDecimals,sontexVolume,sontexVolumeTariff1,sontexVolumeTariff2,sontexVolumeStoredST1,sontexVolumeTariff1ST1,sontexVolumeTariff2ST1,sontexVolumeStoredST2,sontexVolumeTariff1ST2,sontexVolumeTariff2ST2,sontexFlowUnit,sontexFlowDecimals,sontexFlow,sontexTempHighUnit,sontexTempHighDecimals,sontexTempHigh,sontexTempLowUnit,sontexTempLowDecimals,sontexTempLow,sontexTempDiffUnit,sontexTempDiffDecimals,sontexTempDiff,sontexOK,alphaSerial,alphaTotalToGrid,alphaTotalFromGrid,alphaTotalApparentPower,alphaTotalPowerFactor,alphaBatterySOC,alphaBatteryCharging,alphaBatteryDischarging,alphaBatteryChargeRelay,alphaBatteryDischargeRelay,alphaBmuSoftwareVersion,alphaLmuSoftwareVersion,alphaIsoSoftwareVersion,alphaBatteryNum,alphaBatteryCapacity,alphaBatteryType,alphaBatterySoh,alphaBatteryWarning,alphaBatteryFault,alphaBatteryChargeEnergy,alphaBatteryDischargeEnergy,alphaBatteryEnergyChargeFromGrid,alphaBatteryPower,alphaBatteryRemainingMins,alphaBatteryImpChargeSoc,alphaBatteryImpDischargeSoc,alphaBatteryRemainChargeSoc,alphaBatteryRemainDischargeSoc,alphaBatteryMaxChargePower,alphaBatteryMaxDischargePower,alphaBatteryMosClosed,alphaBatterySocCalibEnabled,alphaBatterySingleCutError,alphaBatteryFault1,alphaBatteryFault2,alphaBatteryFault3,alphaBatteryFault4,alphaBatteryFault5,alphaBatteryFault6,alphaBatteryWarning1,alphaBatteryWarning2,alphaBatteryWarning3,alphaBatteryWarning4,alphaBatteryWarning5,alphaBatteryWarning6,alphaBatteryOK,obVoltage,obFrequency,obCurrent,obActivePower,obApparentPower,obReactivePower,obPowerFactor,obImportActiveEnergy,obImportReactiveEnergy,obExportActiveEnergy,obExportReactiveEnergy,obTotalActiveEnergy,obOK

Comment: What's the code you are using to pull in the csv?

Comment: How can we tell, without seeing any code?

Comment: `pd.read_csv` should load all the columns

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a code sample. I have edited the post

Comment: Can you get rid of the compression argument?

Comment: Just tried and it presented the same result

Comment: Unable to reproduce

Comment: Ok, so I tried this with an empty csv with just those headers and it worked. It must be something to do with the data under the headers. the dataframe stops just before a column with data in the format "30/06/2022  03:56:09", could this be the culprit?

Comment: Please provide a complete example of your dataset, featuring headers and at least  couple of rows in such a way that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Well this is very embarrassing. Someone at my company had changed the files on the SFTP server that I was working on so everything was actually working correctly. I was using an old local file to test.